# Is it possible to install packages from another linux distribution?

Tags: package-management, compatibility, shared-library

To be more precise, an executable returns this error:

> error while loading shared libraries: libftdi1.so.2: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory

I can't find that library for ubuntu, but there is one for OpenSuSE so is there some way I can run this application via ubuntu?

Comment: Care to share what you need? I believe that most software will have an equivalent. The lib has to do with usb  and debian + Ubuntu have it: http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/i386/libftdi1 ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Generally, packages from other distributions are going to either fail to work or break your system. Apps may work, but libraries will not. I would like to point out that the "libftdi1" package *does* provide this library, but under a different name, though. All you should do is `sudo ln /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libftdi.so.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libftdi1.so.2`. Note that the "x86_64-linux-gnu" folder may have a different name, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting it using `alien` - though, as @ovc says, it could make a mess:

```
sudo aptitude install alien
```

and then

```
sudo alien -d -i <package_name>.rpm
```

What this does is:

- **sudo**: Super User DO; do something as superuser
- **alien**: calling the "alien" program
- **-d**: convert to debian package (the default option, just added for clarity)
- **-i**: install converted file
- **.rpm**: the RPM you want to install

You should then be able to use:

```
sudo dpkg -i <package name>
```

---

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1128807&p=7093077#post7093077

Comment: This may install the package but it may not run.

Comment: It does not need to run, it is a libary @GeppettvsD'Constanzo - besides, once installed, if the files are in the wrong place, they could be copied to the correct place. Good point though.